# Send emails to the users without requiring EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to make a "noreply" email to send the users. But I dont want to put password in the EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD field. Is it possible? I tried this exact thing with PHP and it was a success. How can I do this using Django?

Comment: Well you need some way of authenticating to your email provider, surely?

Answer (score 1):

Run in terminal:

```
pip3 install python-decouple
```

If you are using python3, but if you are using python2 type only pip instead of pip3

Create .env file in the root of your django project and write:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'blablabla@gmail.com'  #my email
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'fhiahsffd'   #my password
```

Add the line .env in your .gitignore

```
...
#other lines
.env
...
```

In settings.py

```
import os
from decouple import config
...
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
...
```

Doing this your email password is protected, that was the matter I imagine

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't send emails in django without `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`, because you need to authenticate to server(for example: `smtp` server) in order to successfully send emails.

You can use `env` file to store your those values and create environment variable in `settings.py` and these variable will get their value from `env` file.

This way you will be able to send emails in django without mentioning those values in `settings.py` and keep `env` secure and out of git(or any SCM/VCS sotfware you are using.)

Comment: what if my internal network has a plain SMTP server that no need to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running internally, say from a company's server, you can use their SMTP server and send emails without a password. Just change the EMAIL_PORT to the needed email port, adjust the EMAIL_HOST to the company's SMTP server, and change the EMAIL_HOST_USER to the email being used.

Comment: no help :-(
the EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD is also required.